# How to reuse the jquery ajax post request, that is already working, to the autocomplete functionality?

Tags: php, jquery, laravel, jquery-ui

I have a link "Show cities" when is clicked it appears a modal with some cities:

```
<a class="city" id="showCities" 
 data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal2" href=""> Show cities</a>
```

When the user clicks in a city inside the modal the modal closes and in the "`#conferences`" div it appears the conferences that have the column "city" in the conferences table equal to the clicked city. This is working fine with an ajax request.

**Doubt:**

My doubt is because I would like to reuse this part of the code, the ajax request, for a autocomplete search
input with id "#search". When the user writes for example "Ne" in this autocomplete input it appears Newcastle.
This is working fine.

But when the user clicks in Newcastle it should appaer in the div "#conferences" the conferences
that have the city column as "Newcastle". For this part Im in doubt in how to reuse the code of the ajax post request when
the city inside the modal is clicked. Do you know how to achieve that?

As it is when the user clicks in "Newcastle"
he is redirected to "http://proj.test/conferences/where/city/Newcastle" and it appears the conferences where the city is Newcastle (in this case there is only 1):

```
[{"id":2,"name":"conf test","city":"Newcastle",...}]
```

But what should happen is the conferences where city column
is Newcastle appear in the #conferences div.

AutoCompleteController:

```
class AutocompleteController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
    return view('autocomplete.index');
    }

    public function search(Request $request){
        $search = $request->term;
        $conferences = Conference::where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $cities = Conference::where('city', 'LIKE', '%'.$search.'%')->get();

        $data= [];
        foreach ($conferences as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Conferences', 'value' => $value->name, 'url' => 'conference/'.$value->id.'/'.$value->slug];
        }

        foreach ($cities as $key => $value){
            $data[] = ['category'=> 'Cities', 'value' => $value->city, 'url' => 'conferences/where/city/'.$value->city];
        }
        return response($data);
    }
}
```

Autocomplete Jquery:

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
_create: function() {
    this._super();
    this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var that = this,
    currentCategory = "";
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        var li;
        if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
            ul.append( "<li class='ui-autocomplete-category bg bg-light-gray2 h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue'>"
            + item.category + "</li>" );
            currentCategory = item.category;
        }
        li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );
        if ( item.category ) {
        li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
        }
    });
    }
});

$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
    select: function(event, ui) {
    window.location.href = ui.item.url;
}
```

Modal that appears when Show citis is clicked:

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="modal-list row">
                    @foreach($cities as $city)
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <a  class="" name="city" id="{{$city}}">{{$city}}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The div #conferences" that show the conferences, the results:

```
<div class="row" id="conferences">
    @foreach(conferences as $conference)
    <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="{{$conference->image}}" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue">{{$conference->name}}</h5>
            <p class="card-text font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$conference->place}},
                {{$conference->city}}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

jQuery ajax request:

```
$("a[name='city']").on('click', function(){

    $('#showCities').html($(this).text()+' <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>');

        var city = $(this).attr("id");

        $.ajax({

        url: '{{ route('city.conferences',null) }}/' + city,
        type: 'GET',
        success:function(result){
        console.log(result)

        $('#conferences').empty();
        var newConferences='';
        var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";
        $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
        $('#modal2').modal('hide');
        var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);

        newConferences += '<div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-lg-4 col-xl-3 mb-4">\n' +
            '    <div class="card-body">\n' +
                '      <h5 class="card-title h6 font-weight-bold text-heading-blue">'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
                '      <p class="card-text font-size-sm"><i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i> '+conference.city+'</p>\n' +
                '     </div>\n' +
            '   </div>\n';
        });
        $('#conferences').html(newConferences);

        },
        error: function(error) {

        console.log(error.status)
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use data attributes.  As an additional critique, depending on how your AJAX request works, you may not want to use city name as an ID; especially if there can be multiple cities of the same name returned in a request (ID's will collide and produce unexpected results).

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="modal2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ul class="modal-list row" id="cities-list>
                    @foreach($cities as $city)
                    <li class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                        <a class="" data-city-name="{{city}}" name="city" id="{{$city}}">{{$city}}</a>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

For example, I've added some IDs to your code above.  Then you would simply access these values on the click event of your link like so:

```
$('#cities-list li a').on('click', function() {
    // push city name to #conferences div
    $('#conferences').append($('<p />').text($(this).attr('data-city-name')));
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but that part is already working with the question code "jQuery ajax request". My doubt is how to reuse that code to the autocomplete functionality. Because in the autocomplete when the city is clicked the user is redirected to "http://proj.test/conferences/where/city/Newcastle" and it appears the conferences where the city equal to the clicked city instead of the results appear in the conferences div.

Comment: The issue should be because here "$("#search").catcomplete({ source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}", select: function(event, ui) { window.location.href = ui.item.url;} });"" The user is redirected to "proj.test/conferences/where/city/Newcastle" when the city "Newcastle" is clicked, but the user should not be redirected to that page, it should be done the ajax request to that url. Only when a conference name is clicked in the autocomplete input the user should be redirected to the conference details page, and this is working fine, the issue is only when a citiy is clicked.

Comment: Where is `that._renderItemData( ul, item );`?  Can you show that code?

Comment: Essentially, where is the code that draws the link that you're having trouble with?  It apparently isn't in the modal, correct?

Comment: The renderItemData is from the jquery ui plugin. And its in that part that the link is render.

Comment: And the results come from the AutoCompleteController in this part: "foreach ($cities as $key => $value){ $data[] = ['category'=> 'Cities', 'value' => $value->city, 'url' => 'conferences/where/city/'.$value->city]; }". But like this is working like the conference name, when a conference name is clicked the user goes to the that conference details page. But in the case of the cities should be diferent, the user should not be redirected to a page, it should appear in the #conferences div the results.

Comment: Are you saying that you don't have any control over how the links are rendered and that it's un-managed code?  If so, you could also try overriding the behavior of the links' click event with something like `$('#autocomplete li a').on('click', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); /*do something */ });`

Comment: Thanks with "$('#autocomplete li a').on('click', function(e) {
                e.preventDefault(); /*do something */
                alert("test");
            });" just to test the alert dont appears. When the user clicks in the city that appears in the autocomplete input the alert dont appears, the user is redirected to "http://proj.test/conferences/where/city/Newcastle" and the results, in this case is only one appears in that page like: [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "conference test",
"city": "Newcastle",
...}]. But the results should appear in the #conferences div not in other page.

Comment: The code example provided above was just an example.  After a second look at your code it looks like there is a callback in which you are changing the location of the window.  Try this instead: `$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
    select: function(event, ui) {
    /*window.location.href = ui.item.url;*/ alert('test');
}`

Comment: Thanks, the alert also dont appears. Maybe is necessary to have a if "if(ui.item.category=="Conferences")" if the category is Conferences when the user click in a confenrece is redirected to the conference details page. My doubt is in the else, if the user clicked in a city in the autocomplete input how to use the jQuery ajax request that is already working when a city inside the modal is clicked.

Comment: Example with the if and else :" $("#search").catcomplete({source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}", select: function(event, ui) {alert(ui.item);console.log(ui.item.category);if(ui.item.category=="Conferences"){window.location.href = ui.item.url;console.log("Redirecting to " + ui.item.category + ": " + ui.item.url); }else{//????}} });".

Comment: What happens when you comment out the `window.location.href = ui.item.url;`?  Does it still open the link or does it do nothing?

Comment: The user is not redirected but the results also don't appear in the conferences div.

Comment: It doesn't look like the code provided for the select callback of catcomplete() is complete.  It's hard to say without seeing the full code.  Essentially, if you want it to push data to the other div and *not* redirect the user, you would want to comment out the `window.location.href` line and add in something like `$('#conferences').append($('<p />').text(ui.item.name));` or at least `console.log(ui.item)` in order to see what your server is sending back.